# How does the CPU share data with devices through HMM mechanism in Linux?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, gpu, linux-device-driver

HMM stands for [Heterogeneous Memory Management in Linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/mm/hmm.rst). It provide infrastructure and helpers to integrate non-conventional memory (device memory like GPU on board memory) into regular kernel path.

According to the kernel document, it will allocate a portion of pages in the free physical address space for device use. These pages are assigned to `ZONE_DIVICE` and belonging to `MEMORY_DIVICE_PRIVATE` type, which can not directly addressable by the CPU.

> The second mechanism HMM provides is a new kind of ZONE_DEVICE memory that
> allows allocating a struct page for each page of device memory. Those pages
> are special because **the CPU cannot map them**.

According to this meaning, these physical address do not point to anythinge, and the CPU cannot read or write to it. But the document also states that when the device accesses this part of the page, it will migrate the corresponding data to the device's memory.

> However, they allow migrating
> main memory to device memory using existing migration mechanisms and everything
> looks like a page that is swapped out to disk from the CPU point of view.

**So the question arises, what is the migrated data? How does the CPU share data with devices through the HMM mechanism?**